# Verificar se Array esta vazio Ng-Switch

Tags: angularjs

Eu verifico um parametro com uma array que pode ter valores ele ou não. Tenho um Ng-Switch faz uma verificação neste array. Eu gostaria que quando não tivesse nenhum valor mostrasse uma Mensagem.

Eu cheguei a fazer o `ng-switch-when=""`mas não funcionou e também não sei se é o certo.

```
<div ng-repeat="p in ctrl.currentreport.parameters" ng-switch="p.dataType">
                        <div ng-switch-when="">
                            Não há dados
                        </div>
                        <div ng-switch-when="Integer">
                            <reportinteger parameter="p"></reportinteger>
                        </div>
                        <div ng-switch-when="DateTime">
                            <reportdate parameter="p"></reportdate>
                        </div>
                        <div ng-switch-when="Boolean">
                            <reportboolean parameter="p"></reportboolean>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<div ng-switch-default>

           Alguma coisa...   
 </div>
```

Comment: Bom dia, Thavia não funcionou. O objeto parameters vai sempre existir, o que pode existir ou não são os dados contidos nele. E essa seleção eu faço pelo dateType. Teria alguma outra ideia?

Comment: ng-switch-default funciona quando o valor que você está verificando não dá match com nenhum ng-switch-when...Como está o objeto p.dataType?

Comment: Dentro do "parameters" tenho  "dataType": "Integer". mas também tenho "parameters":"{}".

Comment: Entendi, como pode ser que nao tenha o datatype para o ng-swicth verificar, então ele nao vai funcionar mesmo. Vc deve colocar seu ng-switch dentro de uma <div ng-if=''p.dataType"> <div ng-switch-when="Integer">
                            <reportinteger parameter="p"></reportinteger>
                        </div>... </div> e em outra div voce coloca a situação contraria <div ng-if=''!p.dataType"> Alguma coisa</div>

Comment: Não funcionou, o problema é que ela não esta entrando no <div ng-repeat> que é onde eu coloquei o ng-if. Vou colocar o codigo abaixo

Comment: fiz um teste <ng-if="ctrl.currentreport.parameters>...</div> Ele executa na boa. Porém quando eu coloco <ng-if="ctrl.currentreport.parameters.dataType>...</div> ele não executa mesmo tendo o dataType dentro do parameters.

Comment: Seu ctrl.currentreport.parameters é um array de objetos, por isso ele nao acha o dataType, por isso o ng-if tem que ser na div dentro do ng-repeat. Faz um console.log do seu objeto ctrl.currentreport.parameters, mande pra mim q te ajudo num fiddle.

Comment: Como eu faria este console.log? Você quer saber o que esta contido nele?

Comment: <div ng-repeat="t in ctrl.currentreport.parameters">{t}</dv>
 {"name":"KmInicio","description":"Km Inicio","dataType":"Integer","defaultValue":null,"value":null,"required":true,"validValues":{}}
{"name":"KmFim","description":"Km Fim","dataType":"Integer","defaultValue":null,"value":null,"required":true,"validValues":{}}
{"name":"DataInicio","description":"Data Inicio","dataType":"DateTime","defaultValue":null,"value":null,"required":true,"validValues":{}}
{"name":"DataTermino","description":"Data Termino","dataType":"DateTime","defaultValue":null,"value":null,"required":true,"validValues":{}}

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-repeat="p in ctrl.currentreport.parameters">
                        <div ng-if="!p.dataType">
                            Não tem dados
                        </div>
                        <div ng-if="p.dataType">
                            <div ng-switch="p.dataType">
                                <div ng-switch-when="Integer">
                                    <reportinteger parameter="p"></reportinteger>
                                </div>
                                <div ng-switch-when="DateTime">
                                    <reportdate parameter="p"></reportdate>
                                </div>
                                <div ng-switch-when="Boolean">
                                    <reportboolean parameter="p"></reportboolean>
                                </div>
                                <div ng-switch-when="String">
                                    <reportstring parameter="p"></reportstring>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```